# ASP - getting wrong control when widget is added twice on same page

Tags: asp.net

I have a widget with

```
<label id="selectedPageLabel_read".../>
```

and an editor with a textbox wich set the text for this label. Until now, everithing is fine, when i open the editor, it change my label value.
The problem occur when the same widget is added twice on the same page, editing the second widget change the first label and not the second one.
I took a look at their ids and look like "selectedPageLabel_write_1" for first and "selectedPageLabel_write_2" for the second.
I am getting the label control using

```
Container.GetControl<Label>("selectedPageLabel_read", false)
```

How can i solve this? I need to change the second label when editing the second widget.
Thanks!

Comment: how are changing label text, share your widget code.

Comment: just a friendly advice, im sure there are users here who are familiar with your issue and can offer you a solution in a heartbeat, but if you share **ALL** of your relevant code, you will also get help from people who are not familiar with your issue, but are willing to debug your code just to assist you...